# React - set property of object by setState

Tags: reactjs, setstate

So i have object

```
const [rates, setRates] = useState([
    { key: 'rate0', value: 0 },
    { key: 'rate1', value: 0 },
]);
```

I can log it like this.

```
console.log(rates[1].value);
```

How to change property 'value' using setState ?
I tried.

```
SetRate[0](value:3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use de-structuring to create a copy of your state. Change that copy to the value you desire. Note that I set the first element of the array to an object with value set to 3:

```
let temp = [...rates]
temp[0] = {...temp[0], value: 3}
setRates(temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const newRate = {...rates[index], value:3}
const ratesCopy = [...rates]
ratesCopy.splice(index,1,newRate)
setRates(ratesCopy)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const tempRates = [...rates];
tempRates[0].value = 5;
setRates(tempRates)
console.log(rates);
```

Comment: you are mutating object here, this is an antipattern

Comment: @buzatto beginner here trying to contribute will surely search about anti-patterns regarding this thnx

Comment: try to make copies from objects first, like @viet answer

Comment: @buzatto is correct you should always make a copy. Either by splitting `[...arr]` or using another library like `lodash`

Comment: Done thnx yes mutating objects is not good due to reference

Comment: it's getting better. they are nested objects you should be careful with those. if you look @viet or @sinan they make a copy from array but also create another object instead modifying. when you split like `[...]` or `{...}` you make a shallow copy, so if you have nested objects they will remain the same. you could also use some `deepClone` function from libs like lodash for nested objects.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
setRates([{...rates[0], value:'3'}, rates[1]])
```